# MYSQL column default and range

Tags: mysql, sql

I made a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE clients
(
empno     INTEGER     NULL DEFAULT 7654 CHECK ( 7000 <= empno AND                  
empno <= 8000 ),
cname   VARCHAR(20)   NOT NULL
);
```

I wanted no blank fields for cname, default value of 7654 for empno. Also the values for empno must be between 7000 and 8000. Two problems. First, while I cannot put NULL for cname, if I put ' ' it will accept the entry and show up blank. It should reject it. Also, I tried `INSERT INTO clients (cname, empno) VALUES ('JANE', 6789);` 
It should not have accepted it, but it did! I cannot figure out the problem.

Comment: You have to do your own filtering to catch empty strings on your end.

Comment: Setting default values for nullable fields seems like a bit of a contradiction.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Change `empno` field to `NOT NULL`
2. It is a documented feature: MySQL ignores `CHECK` clause.

[From MySql docs](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/create-table.html):

> The CHECK clause is parsed but ignored by all storage engines.

[Report on MySQL Development forum](http://forums.devshed.com/mysql-help-4/check-constraint-in-mysql-945771.html)

A workaround would be to create another table with values from 7000 to 8000 and add Foreign Key constrain, that's inforced by InnoDB and NDB engines. Tell how you'll be using this column, and may be there are beter ways to work around it.

Comment: Okay, so is there any other way to do it for MYSQL?

Comment: @Modaresi, see update. More ways may feaseable, depending on the use of the column.